# How to compare MySQL datetime and JqueryUI datepicker in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have SQL statement, that needs to compare datetime from DB, and JqueryUI datepicker values from client side. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script>   
    $(function() {
         $( "#calendar" ).datepicker({
             maxDate: "+0m +0w"
         });  

    });
</script>
```

```
$date = $_POST['calendar'];
$SQL = "SELECT  $table.item, $table.price, paying_$table.date_bought"
            . " FROM $table"
            . " JOIN paying_$table"
            . " ON $table.id_$table = paying_$table.id_$table"
            . " JOIN users on users.id_user = paying_$table.id_user"
            . " WHERE paying_$table.id_user = '$id' "
            . " AND paying_$table.date_bought BETWEEN  $date AND NOW() ";

$result = $db->query($SQL); //etc etc...
```

$table is var that i get from switch statement, so everything is correct in that part. On what I suspect are last 2 lines of SQL.
When I tried to dump that SQL statement, NOW() function don't execute, it just return string NOW().

Type of date in mysql is datetime.
Thanks

Comment: What format is $date?

Comment: It returns :
01/05/2016

Answer (score 1):

Likely you're comparing dates in different formats. Based on your comment, your format looks like `m/d/Y`, whereas MySQL `DATETIME` field is `Y-m-d H:i:s` (only `Y-m-d` if your field is just `DATE`)

You could easily pre-format your date to match the required format by mysql, by using the php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) native class:

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $_POST['calendar'])->format('Y-m-d')`

Also, quote the $date variable in your query:

```
. " AND paying_$table.date_bought BETWEEN  '$date' AND NOW() ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['calendar'] ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the format of the $date variable? The MySQL DATETIME default format  is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` .